# Socket IO 4.2.0 Log Room Name and Size

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using the latest version of Socket.IO and I am trying to get the room size. But I am not getting the values in console.log.  Please see the code below:

```
// Join Chat Room
socket.join(room2, function(err) {
    
console.log(err)
    
let room2Size = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room2).size
    
console.log('joined-room-' + room2)
console.log('room-size-'+room2Size)
    
})
```

Tried

```
let room2Size =  io._nsps.get('/').adapter.rooms.get(room2).size;
let room2Size = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[room2].sockets;
let room2Size =  io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room2).size
```

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to be working**

```
socket.join(room2);
console.log(socket.rooms);
let room2Size = io.sockets.adapter.rooms.get(room2).size
console.log(room2Size);
```

Things seem to be working without wrapping them in , function(err) { }) - they work in sequential flow basis.